# PrepareForSegue with multiple variables

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, variables

Background: This is my 2nd iphone app ever but I've done other types of coding.

I'm working through this tutorial to create an iOS music player app:
[Build an iOS Music Player](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-an-ios-music-player-player-controls--pre-50351).

It's going pretty good: So far I can populate a table containing the iPhone's playlists. I can select a playlist, get that playlist's persistent ID, and use that to create a query on the next page that populates a table with all the songs in that playlist, plus display the number of songs and the total minutes.

The code in the tutorial works as long as you're only passing one variable (in this case, the album name) - which is given in the tutorial thusly:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    AlbumViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

    MPMediaQuery *albumsQuery = [MPMediaQuery albumsQuery];
    NSArray *albums = [albumsQuery collections];

    int selectedIndex = [[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row];
    MPMediaItem *selectedItem = [[albums objectAtIndex:selectedIndex] representativeItem];
    NSString *albumTitle = [selectedItem     valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle];
//THIS IS WHAT'S PASSING THE VARIABLE                     
    [detailViewController setAlbumTitle:albumTitle];
}
```

I have changed it to this - to be able to work with playlists and because I found that using the persistent ID works better than the name for formulating the resulting query (This code works):

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    PlaylistSongsViewController *varLetsSegueOhYeah = [segue destinationViewController];
    //what are we even looking at again? it's a query
    MPMediaQuery *playlistsQuery = [MPMediaQuery playlistsQuery];
    //identify the query again please?
    NSArray *playlists = [playlistsQuery collections];
    //where are we in the table
    int selectedIndex = [[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row];
    //for that index id, what playlist does that map to
    MPMediaItem *selectedItem = [playlists objectAtIndex:selectedIndex];
    //for that playlist, what is its name
    //NSString *varPlaylistName = [selectedItem     valueForProperty:MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName];
    //for that playlist, what is its persistent id
    NSString *varPlaylistID = [selectedItem     valueForProperty:MPMediaPlaylistPropertyPersistentID];
//THIS IS WHAT'S PASSING THE VARIABLE
    [varLetsSegueOhYeah setVarPlaylistID:varPlaylistID];
}
```

HOWEVER I would like to be able to pass TWO variables - the persistent ID AND the playlist name, so I can display that at the top of the destination screen. You can see in the code above that the line that actually grabs the playlist name is commented out - this is because apparently if you grab the value but don't actually use it, the app crashes. But it's there to show you what that part would look like if I did know how to use it. Both variables are properly declared in the ViewController.h of the destination screen.

**I have googled around and tried various guesses and combinations but nothing has worked so far.** So in summary - I know how to send 1 variable, now how do I send 2?

Edit: The destination screen code

**PlaylistSongsViewController.m**
starts out like this:

```
#import "PlaylistSongsViewController.h"

@interface PlaylistSongsViewController ()

@end

@implementation PlaylistSongsViewController
@synthesize varPlaylistName;
@synthesize varPlaylistID;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = varPlaylistName;
}
```

And the rest of it can be found [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-an-ios-music-player-player-controls--pre-50351) under "Step 3: Show the Album Songs & Info" except I've replaced "album" with "playlist".

**PlaylistSongsViewController.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface PlaylistSongsViewController : UITableViewController
{
    NSString *varPlaylistName;
    NSString *varPlaylistID;
}
//albumTitle in tutorial

@property NSString *varPlaylistName;
@property NSString *varPlaylistID;

@end
```

Comment: Can you be very specific? I tried a bunch of things and none of them worked.

Comment: What is the crash when you uncomment that line?

Comment: I was mistaken - it's not really a crash. The UI just hangs. The debug area shows a yellow alert for "Unused variable" and a green line around     [varLetsSegueOhYeah setVarPlaylistID:varPlaylistID];

Answer (score 0):

You can set as many variables as you need:

```
[varLetsSegueOhYeah setVarPlaylistID:varPlaylistID];
[varLetsSegueOhYeah setVarPlaylistName:varPlaylistName];
```

You can also directly access the property:

```
varLetsSegueOhYeah.varPlaylistID = varPlaylicstID;
varLetsSegueOhYeah.varPlaylistName = varPlaylistName;
```

then in `viewDidLoad`:

```
NSLog(@"varPlaylistID = %@",self.varPlaylistID);
NSLog(@"varPlaylistName = %@",self.varPlaylistName);
```

Make sure you declare the properties in your interface file:

```
@property (nonatomic , strong) NSString* varPlaylicstID;
@property (nonatomic , strong) NSString* varPlaylistName;
```

And note you don't need to synthesize your properties like it used to be, it is automatically done now.

Comment: It doesn't seem to like that. The debug area sends back all the values which look fine, but the UI doesn't proceed to the next screen.

Comment: OK I added it to the description.

Comment: I added the above the viewDidLoad and tried reformatting the segue vars as you have them here; without brackets just gives the same result as before; with brackets makes the build fail.

Comment: the method and properties need to be declared in the interface file or it wont compile. just do the same thing you did with the first one

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding - both variables are declared in PlaylistSongsViewController.h and PlaylistSongsViewController.m. I added to the description.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ([segue.destinationViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(setVarPlaylistID:)]) {

        [segue.destinationViewController setVarPlaylistID:varPlaylistID];
        [segue.destinationViewController setVarPlaylistName:varPlaylistName];
        [segue.destinationViewController setAnotherVariable:variableNameOfCorrectType];

} else NSLog(%@"Segue does not respond to selector");
```

In the destinationViewController, you will have to declare and synthesize as so:

```
NSString* varPlaylistID;
.
.
.
@synthesize varPlaylistID = _varPlaylistID;

//Declare setter
-(void) setVarPlaylistID:(NSString *)varPlaylistID
{
_varPlaylistID = varPlaylistID;
}
```

Do the same for varPlaylistName.

Comment: Thanks, can you help me know where exactly to place this in my code? I tried dropping it in at the end but then it doesn't like that varLetsSegueOhYeah is unused.

Comment: Put it at the end of prepareForSegue and use it to replace [varLetsSegueOhYeah setVarPlaylistID:varPlaylistID];
I will edited my answer to display the selectors you will have to your destination view controller.

Comment: OK did that and tried different things to get rid of the unused variable it didn't like; same result as before.

Comment: Step through prepareForSegue and ensure that you are going into if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Okay - I finally got it to work. I identified my problems:

1. I didn't realize that we're not so much "passing global variables" as I'm used to thinking of them, as independent envelopes of information. They are
   more akin form fields that are attached to each object type and we
   send instructions for filling them in.
2. Because of that I think my messy thought process was confusing for the compiler to make sense of.
3. After getting rid of "@synthesize", I couldn't figure out when it wanted "_" before a property name and when it wanted "self.". I sort
   of just got through this with trial and error and having a clearer
   idea of what was going on conceptually.

   4. I didn't realize that I had breakpoints set in the compiler that was causing it to hang in the UI when it otherwise would not have. Oops.

New PlaylistsController.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface PlaylistsViewController : UITableViewController


@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *varSelectedPlaylistID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *varSelectedPlaylistName;


@end
```

This is stating that we're going to be finding out the values for what the user selected for playlist id and playlist name.

New PlaylistSongsController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface PlaylistSongsViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *varPlaylistIDToDisplay;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *varPlaylistNameToDisplay;

@end
```

This is stating that we're going to be using some values to display a particular playlist name and ID.

New PlaylistsController PrepareForSegue:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    //First - identify what the user has selected.

    //define query
    MPMediaQuery *playlistsQuery = [MPMediaQuery playlistsQuery];
    //dump query results into array
    NSArray *playlists = [playlistsQuery collections];

    //identify user selected table row
    int selectedIndex = [[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row];
    //map user selected table row to array item
    MPMediaItem *selectedItem = [playlists objectAtIndex:selectedIndex];


    //assign selected values to properties of the object we're looking at right now. They have underscores here for some reason!
    _varSelectedPlaylistID = [selectedItem valueForProperty:MPMediaPlaylistPropertyPersistentID];
    _varSelectedPlaylistName = [selectedItem valueForProperty:MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName];


    //now let's get ready to go. for an object of type "Playlist Songs View Controller, we want to create a new instance of that and name it MyNewPlaylistInstance and then go to there.
    PlaylistSongsViewController *MyNewPlaylistInstance = [segue destinationViewController];

    //when we get to MyNewPlaylistInstance, it will want to know which playlist ID and name to use - tell it to use the values we just set
    MyNewPlaylistInstance.varPlaylistIDToDisplay = self.varSelectedPlaylistID;
    MyNewPlaylistInstance.varPlaylistNameToDisplay = self.varSelectedPlaylistName;
}

    @end
```